# Designing an experiment to assess the form of a distance measure

Tags: references, experiment-design, distance

BACKGROUND: I do research in [budget-proposal aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget-proposal_aggregation): each person reports their ideal budget-allocation, and a central authority has to decide on an actual budget-allocation. An important component in designing such procedures is the form of the voters' dis-utility function: given that a voter's ideal budget is X and the actual budget is Y, how much unhappiness does the voter feel?

To illustrate, suppose a budget of 100 has to be allocated among four issues, and your ideal budget-allocation is 10,20,30,40. What actual budget would make you more unhappy: (a) 20,10,40,30, or (b) 10,20,15,55?

One way to describe a dis-utility is through a *metric*. In the above example, consider two options:

- Your dis-utility is based on an $\ell_1$ metric: then (a) gives you dis-utility $10+10+10+10=40$, and (b) gives you dis-utility $0+0+15+15=30$, so you prefer (b).
- Your dis-utility is based on an $\ell_2$ metric: then (a) gives you dis-utility $\sqrt{10^2+10^2+10^2+10^2}=\sqrt{400}$, and (b) gives you dis-utility $\sqrt{0^2+0^2+15^2+15^2}=\sqrt{450}$, so you prefer (a).

I would like to design an experiment in order to assess the form of a single person's dis-utility function: is it based on $\ell_1$ or $\ell_2$ or another metric, or maybe it is not based on a metric at all. The experiment will probably involve pairwise comparisons, such as persenting the person with (a) and (b) and asking what he/she prefers; but I do not know how exactly to generate the pairs in an efficient way?

Also, are there any papers that describe a similar experiment?

Comment: Putting aside realism concerns, mathematically your budgets sum to 1/100 and each component is, presumably , >= 0. Therefore you are working on a standard simplex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex), with no obvious choice for a basis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) and the $\ell_p$-metrics are not basis independent.

Comment: @LukasLohse yes, the amounts sum to a fixed number (say 100), so the set of possible budget allocations is a simplex.  But I did not understand the last claim. What do you mean by "the $\ell_p$ metrics are not basis independent", and how is it related to the experiment I am planning?

Comment: I had assumed you would calculate the metric with coordinates in a appropriate basis, but I guess you can just use the canonical $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the approaches used to measure risk and loss aversion in cognitive science, like [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9942526/)?

Comment: This is a nice problem, because it's also easy to do parameter recovery studies, where you simulate responses from agents using the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ metrics (plus softmax noise) and see how reliably you can tell which is which for a given collection of pairs.

Comment: It's also easy to calculate the efficiency of a pair of options here: it's the likelihood that $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ agents will choose different options. Again, the softmax decision-rule is crucial here.

Comment: Final aside: There are people who say you can use staircases/active learning approaches for this kind of problem. Don't. I did some work showing that this leads to all kinds of complications (and left for industry before I got around to publishing it).

Comment: Final final aside: I'd bet you money that the order of the pairs, and the order of the dis-utilities within each option matter as well, but you'll just have to randomise those for now.

Comment: @Eoin I am vaguely familiar with studies for measuring risk attitudes, but these studies usually ask people to compare lotteries. In my scenario, everything is deterministic - there are no lotteries.

Comment: The randomness of the lottery is irrelevant, the theory is that the subjective utility of each lottery depends on the form of the participant's risk and loss aversion functions, and they choose the option with highest subjective utility (with some decision noise).

Comment: Since your data lives on a Simplex, your metric/(dis-)utility should be defined on a Simplex as well. Everything else will create arbitrary effects. Have a look at the article [compositional data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data). 
The basic idea is to use the so called ilr-transform to pass from the Simplex to a $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Then do whatever you want to do (define a metric or utility or do statistical inference) in this space and finally translate the results back to the Simplex.

Comment: @gg transforming a simplex to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is not difficult. But what do I do in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$  - how can I plan the experiment to determine the form of utility functions?

Comment: I think this is quite futile unless you have strong prior assumptions for a preference function. Once you are in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ any function $f$ without critical points will provide a candidate by assuming folks prefer $A$ to $B$ iff $f(A)>f(B)$. So the best way to go forward may be to ask yourself what properties this preference should have. Then design a family of functions with these properties and only then try to do tests. Otherwise linear functionals may be a good place to start. It seems doable to design questions to elicit the coefficients in this special case. (If there are any)

Comment: @gg but my main problem is to find the family (e.g. decide whether it is linear, quadratic, or something else), not to find the coefficients.

Comment: I do not think this is realistic. No finite amount of data will help you there, since from a pure mathematics perspective there are far too many possibilities. You need properties of the preferences to cut back and to weed out families which are unreasonable in the first place.

Comment: This paper may be a helpful place to look for ideas: The non-Riemannian nature of perceptual color space https://www.pnas.org/doi/epdf/10.1073/pnas.2119753119

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm consolidating a few points I made in the comments. This isn't a comprehensive answer to your question, because I think the real answer is that you need to collaborate with some experimental cognitive scientists if you want to run this kind of cognitive science experiment.

First, you need to decide if your goal is to test between the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ metrics, or to explore the functional form of the utility function without having any strong hypotheses about the shape. They're different goals, and require very different experimental designs, but the first is probably where you should start.

I was going to say that for the former goal, you only need to generate pairs of scenarios where the ideal allocation is the same and the total budget is the same, but the actual allocation differs between the two options so that one option is better under $\ell_1$ utility, the other under $\ell_2$ utility. However, looking at this, I realised that if the ideal allocations and the budgets are the same for both problems, all allocations have the same $\ell_1$ utility (excluding cases where you overspend on any issue). As a result, this design really just lets you test whether people are sensitive to something like $\ell_2$ utility (they prefer allocations where the shortfall is shared more equally across all issues, or where the variance of the dis-utility is low) or not (they're indifferent).

To get around this issue, you might consider a simpler exploratory experiment. Generate a whole load of scenarios, with different budgets, ideal allocations, and actual allocations. Ask people to rate the fairness of the allocation, using a 1-9 scale or something like that. Plot everything against everything and see how the curves look.

Comment: Why do all allocations have the same $\ell_1$  utility? If the ideal budget is, say, 10,20,30,40, then 20,10,30,40 has $\ell_1$  disutility 20, but 0,30,30,40 has $\ell_1$  disutility 40. Regarding your first comment: collaborating with cognitive scientists is a good idea. As a start, do you know of some papers from cognitive science describing a similar experiment?

Comment: I think we're maybe using different definitions, but `c(10,20,30,40) - c(20,10,30,40) = c(-10, 10, 0, 0)`, and `c(10,20,30,40) - c(0,30,30,40) = c(10, -10, 0, 0)`, so they should have the same $\ell_1$ utility?

Comment: I don't have a single authoritative reference to hand, but have you read Tversky and Kahneman's classic papers on subjective expected utility?

Comment: Sorry, I meant (30,0,30,40). The difference is `c(20,-20,0,0)` which gives 40.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, excluding cases where you overspend on any issue. Maybe you do want to study cases where there's overspend, in which case my point doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Using an experiment to distinguish $\ell^1$ from $\ell^2$ metrics of disutility is probably hopeless —- because people are likely to state preferences that can not be modeled by either.

For instance, people may state intransitive preferences. If you ask about any particular level of the administrative budget, they may prefer to reduce it by 10%, but if you ask about reducing the admin budget to 1/3 of its current size, they may prefer the status quo. Good luck modeling that with $\ell^p$ utilities!

If you instead ask for 1-10 ratings, as Eoin suggests, people may state discontinuous ratings: they may only give ratings in the 1-3 or 8-10 ranges. Good luck fitting that well with $\ell^p$ utilities!

There is a literature on this, in empirical studies of non-expected utility, and maybe you can model the preferences of the crowd that you survey, but that might not be a good enough reason to follow the model in your own budgetary decisions.

So if the central authority wants a genuinely participatory budget process, it might be better off by transparently taking a weighted average of the proposed allocations, with the weights given in advance. This may highlight the need for vetting which proposals are allowed to go into the average at all, but that would be equally necessary even in the more complicated and less transparent approaches.